# Problema con ejercicio de java de lectura y escritura de ficheros

Tags: java

> Escribe un programa que reciba como argumentos un carácter y una cadena de caracteres. El programa debe leer el fichero de texto cuyo nombre se ha recibido como segundo argumento y mostrar en pantalla aquellas líneas que contengan el carácter indicado como primer argumento.

Estoy atascado y no se como plantearlo en java.

```
import java.io.*;

class LeeFichero {
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        File archivo = null;
        try {
            archivo = new File("archivo.txt");
            String linea;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivo);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            int i,j,aux=0;
            while((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
                for(i=0;i<linea.length();i++)
                {
                    if(linea.charAt(i)=='a')
                    {
                        if(i==0) 
                            aux=1;
                        else
                        {
                            if(linea.charAt(i-1)==' ')
                                aux=1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(aux==1)
                    {
                        if(linea.charAt(i)!=' ')
                            System.out.print(linea.charAt(i));
                        else 
                        {
                            aux=0; System.out.println(' ');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException a){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi ejercicio, yo lo he planteado el cual me saca todas las palabras que empiecen por a, pero lo que quiero hacer es que me diga donde en que lineas se encuentra la a como puedo modificarlo

Comment: Hola @Ángel, edita el mensaje con al menos el código que has estado intentando hasta ahora para poder analizar lo hecho hasta el momento.

Comment: Hola Angel. Las preguntas de Tareas no suelen ser bienrecibidas en este sitio. A menos que, como dice Eduardorq, añadas lo que has intentado y los errores que te salen o problemas que te surgen. Un saludo ^^

Answer (score 1):

Esto te puede ayudar:

```
package app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Paolo Rios Garaundo
 */
public class Executable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            /*
            Contenido de a.txt
                hola como estas?
                este es un mensaje de
                ejemplo, solo para ver
                si se encuentran los caracteres
                especificados.
            */
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\a.txt"));
            List lineasConTexto = new ArrayList(); // donde el primer indice del arreglo es la line en el fichero y el segundo indice es la posicion del texto en la linea
            int numLinea = 0;
            String ln;

            while((ln = br.readLine()) != null){
                int pos = ln.indexOf("un");
                if (pos > -1) {// si la linea contiene la palabra 'un'
                    lineasConTexto.add(new Integer[] {numLinea, pos});
                }

                numLinea++;
            }

            // se recorre los datos recaudados
            for (Integer[] arr : lineasConTexto){
                System.out.println("Linea: " + arr[0] + " - Posicion en la linea: " + arr[1]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si el problema se ha solucionado, evalúa marcar la respuesta como correcta, podrías así ayudar a más personas.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir la línea que tiene el carácter que necesitas sólo pon tu While de la siguiente forma.

```
while((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
if(línea.contains(caracter+"")
System.out.println(linea);

}
```

La variable **caracter** es el carácter que estás buscando en cada línea.

Answer (score 0):

Solución Completa:

```
public class AplicacionJava {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        buscaCaracter('z',"c:\\Archivo.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //manejar la excepcion
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


public static void buscaCaracter(char caracter,String archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File documento = new File(archivo);
        String linea;
        FileReader fr;

        fr = new FileReader (documento);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
            if(linea.contains(caracter+""))
            System.out.println(linea);


        }

}
```

}

Comment: ¿Nos explica qué hace el código y cómo responde a la pregunta del op?